# Have I transformed this reported speech correctly?

Tags: modal-verbs, indirect-speech, indirect-question

> She asked the teacher what should she do.

Should it read as -

> She asked the teacher, What has to be done?

Please explain why the sentence might be incorrect.

Comment: Do you mean paraphrasing?
If so, I think the answer is yes.

Comment: Welcome! This is a homework question, isn't it? That's fine, but you need to show your work: why do *you* think the rephrasing might be incorrect? If you don't show us that you've made an effort to answer this yourself, and you don't point out exactly why you're having difficulty, then unfortunately we can't answer this.

Answer (score 2):

The sentence

> She asked the teacher what should she do.

Is not written or spoken by a native speaker I assume.
I would guess what is meant is:

> She asked the teacher what she should do.

And that sentence does indeed mean:

> She asked the teacher: "What should I do?"